# "The sample rate of the two audio tracks is different"

Tags: ffmpeg, bitrate

I'm trying to merge a few video files through `mkvmerge` but I get the following error after running

```
mkvmerge -o '/home/videos/marged/new.mp4' '/home/videos/intro.mp4' \+ 'old.mp4' \+ '/home/videos/intro.mp4'
```

Error:

```
Error: The track number 1 from the file 'old.mp4' cannot be appended to the track number 1 from the file '/home/videos/intro.mp4'. The sample rate of the two audio tracks is different: 44100 and 22050
```

Is there a way to force this? If not how can I change the audio to the same rate as `old.mp4` in ffmpeg for `/home/videos/intro.mp4`

Answer (score 2):

To force to 44100 Hz, command template is

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 new.mp4
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the merge?

Comment: Using mkvmerge, don't see a way. Playback speed would be wrong for 2nd file even if you could.